# Show bullets in Materialize List

Tags: jquery, css, material-design, materialize

I'm currently using Materialize, however on the default setting lists (both ordered and unordered) are displayed as plain text without bullet points.

Is there a workaround to override this and make them look more natural?

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html) it's enough to use the .browser-default class to revert UL, SELECT and INPUT elements to their original state

Comment: @gantzer89 and what if you are using an overhead like a markdown syntax in which you cannot define and your users want/expect the default HTML behavior? This question should not have been frozen. To change the default behavior is not ok, Materialize is a great package although this mistake is serious and should be changed.

Comment: Because Materialize override many of the default browser styles and elements, it provides the `.browser-default` class to revert these elements to their original state: you have to add it to `ul` element, as said here: https://materializecss.com/helpers.html#browser-default

Answer (score 3):

Because you have    `list-style-type: none`.
Force your    `list-style-type` to default with `!important`.

```
list-style-type: circle !important
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer, seems like materialize has `list-style-type: none` on default. So I just changed it to square.

Comment: Great, I hope I still helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the style property 
  `list-style-type: initial;` with your `<li>` tags